# Manually installing libraries for cross compilation

Tags: libraries

I'm trying to cross compile a program with needs the -lgcrypt flag.  I have copied the root filesystem of the machine I'm compiling for so that I have all the libraries which are needed to be able to compile that program.  It builds just fine on that machine, but due to the fact it's a large program I need to be able to compile it a bit faster on an x86_64 machine.

The problem is that I have absolutely no idea where my linker is looking for these libraries or how to get it to recognize them.  I've been tinkering around with this for a few hours now and cannot seem to get it figured out.

Any help?